# How to avoid printing the output twice

Tags: ruby

I wrote the following code to read from a file and print out the output in the terminal. I am getting output but instead of it printing out once like:

```
Crackling Rose

sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.wav

Soolaimon

sounds/06-Soolaimon.wav

Sweet Caroline

sounds/20-Sweet_Caroline.wav
```

I am getting the output twice like:

```
Crackling Rose

sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.wav

Soolaimon

sounds/06-Soolaimon.wav

Sweet Caroline

sounds/20-Sweet_Caroline.wav

Crackling Rose

sounds/01-Cracklin-rose.wav

Soolaimon

sounds/06-Soolaimon.wav

Sweet Caroline

sounds/20-Sweet_Caroline.wav
```

Any ideas why that might be?

This is my code:

```
class Track
    attr_accessor :name, :location

    def initialize (name, location)
        @name = name
        @location = location
    end
end

# Returns an array of tracks read from the given file
def read_tracks(a_file)

  count = a_file.gets().to_i()
  i=0
  tracks = Array.new()
  while (i<count)
    track = read_track(a_file)
    tracks << track
    i+=1
  end 

  return tracks
end

# reads in a single track from the given file.
def read_track(a_file)
  track_name=a_file.gets.chomp
  track_location = a_file.gets.chomp
  track = Track.new(track_name, track_location)
  track.name= track_name
  track.location= track_location
  return track

end

# Takes an array of tracks and prints them to the terminal
def print_tracks(tracks)
  index = 0
  while (index<tracks.length)
    print_track tracks[index]
      index+=1
    end 
end

# Takes a single track and prints it to the terminal
def print_track(track)
    puts(track.name)
    puts(track.location)
end

# Open the file and read in the tracks then print them
def main()
  a_file = File.new("input.txt", "r") # open for reading
  tracks=read_tracks(a_file)
  print_tracks(tracks)
  # Print all the tracks
  print_tracks(tracks)
end

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. When asking about a bug in your program, please supply the absolute minimal input in addition to the smallest piece of code that demonstrates the problem, along with your expected output. Without those, we'll come up with our own requirements which can wander spectacularly from the reality you enjoy. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"

Answer (score 5):

First of all you are calling `print_tracks(tracks)` twice in `main()` method

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `print_tracks()` twice in here

```
# Open the file and read in the tracks then print them
def main()
  a_file = File.new("input.txt", "r") # open for reading
  tracks=read_tracks(a_file)
  print_tracks(tracks)
  # Print all the tracks
  print_tracks(tracks)
end
```